# Itextsharp can't extract pdf unicode content in c#

Tags: c#, pdf, unicode, itext, persian

I am trying to get the content of pdf file using `itextsharp` as you can see :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(@"D:\a.pdf"))
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
        {
            text.Append(PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i));
        }
    }
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"c:/a.txt",text.ToString());
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

My pdf content is written in `Persian` ,and after running the above code to result is like this :

[image]

But this is not correct result.should i set any option in `itextsharp`

Comment: As you don't show the PDF you extracted from, it is hard to tell anything.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say without an original file but in case you have characters/words incorrectly placed then you should try to use `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` like this:

`text.Append(PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i, new LocationTextExtractionStrategy());`