# extracting Arabic text in c# by using itextsharp

Tags: c#, itext

[image]I have this code and I'm using it to take the text of a PDF. It's great for a PDF in English but when I'm trying to extract the text in Arabic it shows me something like this.

> ")  +  n  9  n <+,  + )+ $   # $   +$ F%   9& .< $  : ;"

```
using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path))
{
     ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
     String text = "";
     for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
     {
          text = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i,strategy);
     }

}
```

Comment: This looks like the pdf does not contain the information required for text extraction according to the pdf specification.

Comment: Did you try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35436158/itextsharp-cant-extract-pdf-unicode-content-in-c-sharp ?

Comment: no there are a lot of words but the itextsharp codes the Arabic words

Comment: @KMoussa it didont solve my problem 
still coding it like " ,  -%&  ,. &$, $/  . %  -%  ) $   ( +% ) & !" +/ ) $  ( 12  . 3$) ( $ 45 .(  3$) %& ,5  6   7 !8$     # & *  .  3$) +8   $ +8 9 3$,  -: .(  3$) . +8 ).  15 + $ $  %& $ 7" $,    $ ,5 . .(  3$) ) $  ) & ( .    : ,5$  3(& .   -(5$$ 2) %& $5 8$2) $/ $   "

Comment: Please share a sample file to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @mkl i add picture showing the output after extraction

Comment: Obviously we cannot reproduce the issue using a picture...

Comment: A picture doesn't help. If you don't want to share the PDF, try doing `copy/paste` of the text in Adobe Reader? Do you get the same result as with iText? If so: you can't extract the Arabic text correctly because **the PDF doesn't contain the information required for text extraction according to the PDF specification** (which was the very first comment you got on this question).

Comment: here's the out :ق ديمحلا دبع : 
:يبابضلا قطنملا فيرعت 
اقيبطتو ةريبخلا ةمظنلأا ضعب يف مدختسي ،قطنملا لاكشأ دحأ وه ت  ءاكذلا يعانصلا ماع قطنملا اذه أشن 5691 صلأا يناجيبرذلأا ملاعلا دي ىلع ل 
"
an the orginal "
هو أحد أشكال المنطق، يستخدم في بعض الأنظمة الخبيرة وتطبيقات الذكاء
الصناعي نشأ هذا المنطق عام 5691 على يد العالم الأذربيجاني الأصل
"ل
." 
i'm really grateful if you help me
@BrunoLowagie

Comment: Are you using the latest iText version? Older versions weren't able to extract Arabic text correctly.

Comment: i'm using version 5.5.8.0

Comment: @BrunoLowagie it's done i reverse the string but i want to save the English words do you have any idea

Comment: You have to check the Unicode range and only reverse the characters in the "Arabic range".

Comment: @BrunoLowagie thnx sir it's done

Answer (score 6):

I had to change the strategy like this

```
var t = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i, new LocationTextExtractionStrategy());
var te = Convert(t);
```

and this function to reverse the Arabic words and keep the English

```
  private string Convert(string source)
  {
       string arabicWord = string.Empty;
       StringBuilder sbDestination = new StringBuilder();

       foreach (var ch in source)
       {
           if (IsArabic(ch))
               arabicWord += ch;
           else
           {
               if (arabicWord != string.Empty)
                    sbDestination.Append(Reverse(arabicWord));

               sbDestination.Append(ch);
               arabicWord = string.Empty;
            }
        }

        // if the last word was arabic    
        if (arabicWord != string.Empty)
            sbDestination.Append(Reverse(arabicWord));

        return sbDestination.ToString();
     }


     private bool IsArabic(char character)
     {
         if (character >= 0x600 && character <= 0x6ff)
             return true;

         if (character >= 0x750 && character <= 0x77f)
             return true;

         if (character >= 0xfb50 && character <= 0xfc3f)
             return true;

         if (character >= 0xfe70 && character <= 0xfefc)
             return true;

         return false;
     }

     // Reverse the characters of string
     string Reverse(string source)
     {
          return new string(source.ToCharArray().Reverse().ToArray());
     }
```

Comment: None of the characters the output in your question shows is in the ranges tested for in `IsArabic`. If the code from your answer really helps, therefore, you didn't present the data you really extracted in your question...

Comment: actually it happens for some and espcially when it was old version :)

Comment: OK, thank you for sharing this code. I'm sure it will be helpful for other people too.

Comment: I'm really grateful for helping me :)